# outputting mulitple numbers into an array?

Tags: javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < firstString.length; i++) {
  newArray.push(i);
  return newArray;
}
```

What code am i missing? Outputting `[0]`, when i want to output `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]`

What exactly am i doing with my code, since it's not what i think?

I've seen this --->

```
function someFunction(n){
  var newArray = [];
  for(var i=0; i < n.length; i++){
    newArray.push(n[i]);
  }
  return newArray;
}
```

but i'm not looking to get the length of a function.

Comment: What do you think that `return newArray` line does in your loop?

Comment: @johnny mopp gain that rep! Answer!

Comment: @Jonasw Thanks, but as it says in my profile, I don't worry about rep. Just happy to help :)

Comment: @Jonasw I am curious, though-- what does the OP think it does?

Comment: @alex the best answers do not contain an answer. They give you a point into the right direction, and youll be happy that you find the solution by yourself...

Answer (score 1):

**return** will cause the code to exit the current method. Since you have put the return *inside* the for loop, your method is exiting after the first pass through the loop, thus returning only the output [0].

Move your return newArray; outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `return` statement out of the for loop, because it exits the function and the iteration.

```
for (var i = 0; i < firstString.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(i);
}
return newArray;
```